# How to format multiple date formats into one in R?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to get a single column of dates to all be formatted the same way in R.  However, there are a LOT of different versions of the date.

I've looked at other answers on stackoverflow but none of them have included all of these versions of the date (for example July 4, 1999):

- 7/4/99
- 07/04/99
- 7/4/1999
- 07/04/1999
- 070499
- 7499
- 07041999
- 741999
- 7-4-99
- 07-04-99
- 7-4-1999
- 07-04-1999

I have tried removing all of the '-' and '/' so I am left with just numbers, but it looks like the problem is with the days/months that are only one digit.
I tried

```
if(nchar(data$birthday) == 6) (data$birthday = paste0("0", data$birthday))
```

but that only solves the problem if the month is written with one digit.

This is the closest I think I've gotten, but it's still producing errors.

```
data$newbirthday <- multidate(data$birthday, c("%m%d%Y", "%m%d%y", "%m/%d/%Y", "%m/%d/%y","%m-%d-%Y","%m-%d-%y")
```

- The results from that format two versions fine: 07/04/99 and 07-04-99
- But two versions switch the year to 2019: 07/04/1999 and 07-04-1999
- And two versions are NA: 741999 7499

Comment: I think there cant be an exact solution without restricting the possible timeframe. 
For example the 121299 could be the 1-2-1299 or the 12-12-99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `lubridate` to flexibly (and cleverly) parse different date formats.

In your case, we get

```
ss <- c(
    "7/4/99", "07/04/99", "7/4/1999",
    "07/04/1999", "070499", "7499",
    "07041999", "741999", "7-4-99",
    "07-04-99", "7-4-1999", "07-04-1999")

library(lubridate)
dmy(ss)
#[1] "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07"
#[6] NA           "1999-04-07" NA           "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07"
#[11] "1999-04-07" "1999-04-07"
#Warning message:
# 2 failed to parse.
```

What remains are 2 (ambiguous) dates that give `NA`. Note that all dates that were recognised by `lubridate::dmy` are correct.

The bad ones here are `"7499"` and `"741999"`, which are both ambiguous; for example, consider `"11199"`: Is that supposed to be "11 Jan 1999" or "1 Nov 1999"? There's no way of telling. Ditto for `"1111999"`.

So in fact, `lubridate` returning `NA` is the correct result, as these dates cannot be (and should not get) parsed.

Comment: Ah!  Okay, that helps a lot.  
I need all of the rows to have a working date though, as the next thing I'm doing is calculating age using "data$age = as.numeric(difftime(data$date, data$birthday, unit="weeks"))/52.25", where the date and the birthday are not the same.
Any suggestions for a good workaround?

Comment: @Rachel Well as I explain there really isn't a "workaround", as dates are ambiguous. Meaning there are multiple realistic possibilities, see my example above.